# RewriteRule in .htaccess showing rewritten url in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apologies if this has been asked before but I've searched all over for an answer to this but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution.

I've got the following .htaccess file in my httpdocs:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ users/$1 [L]
```

This correctly maps "www.example.com/joebloggs" to "www.example.com/users/jobloggs" and the appropriate index page is correctly shown.

The problem is "www.example.com/users/jobloggs" is shown in the address bar instead of the original (short) url. Would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying it's loading a `DirectoryIndex` file (e.g. `index.html` / `index.php`), then I'd say the lack of a trailing slash in your `RewriteRule` substitution is the problem.  Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ users/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the slash does fix the address bar problem. But as you perhaps alluded to in your answer the rule(s) are still not quite right. I cannot now navigate to the other pages as clicking links will take me to www.example.com/thelink.html instead of www.example.com/joebloggs/thelink.html.

Comment: What URL do you have in your source code?  Do you have `/thelink.html`?

Comment: There is essentially an entire site under each user directory. With the RerwiteRule that i now have, if i browse to www.example.com/joebloggs i can see the index page but cannot navigate the site. If i browse to www.example.com/joebloggs/ (note the trailing slash) it works fine.

Comment: It sounds like you have URLs in your source code that are relative to the document URL, e.g.: `<a href="thelink.html">` or `<a href="./thelink.html">`. If that's the case then the trailing slash is significant in how the browser will resolve the links, so you should probably do an external redirect to make sure it's included. Without the trailing slash it will try to resolve them relative to the base URL for the whole site. With the trailing slash it'll be relative to `/joebloggs/`, e.g. `/joebloggs/thelink.html`. Alternatively use URLs like `/joebloggs/thelink.html` in your source.

Comment: Sorry, I think you lost me there. I dont want to modify the source links. But I also dont want the browser to show that the site is under /users.